# How do I execute cron service in linux?

Tags: linux, service, cron

I am trying to run a Python code every minute in Linux but at loss to configure cron service.  Following is what I added after running 'crontab -e' but nothing is happening.

```
* * * * * cd /home/kali && /usr/bin/python3.8 /home/kali/time.py
```

time.py contains simple code to show current time.

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to add it to crontab,try:
sudo nano /etc/crontab
and after that you can put your service:
 * * * * * cd /home/kali && /usr/bin/python3.8 /home/kali/time.py
Check it again 'sudo crontab -e'

Comment: I was hoping to see the time on the terminal screen but didn' work; however dumping and appending into a file using,"* * * * * cd /home/kali && /usr/bin/python3.8 /home/kali/time.py >> out.txt" worked.

Answer (score 0):

you should run your code with python3. i dont understand why you use cd command, so i omit that.

This is the way you can run your python code in cron:

```
* * * * * python3  /home/kali/time.py
```

**Note**: Check if you have **permission** to execute .py file.